# Evaluating derivatives

Tags: derivatives

"If the tangent line to $y = f(x)$ at $(4,3)$ passes through the point $(0, 2)$, find $f(4) $and $f'(4)$"

I'm not sure even where to start on this. The language of this problem is very confusing to me, I don't have good English. I would think f(4) = 4 since y = f(x), but that seems too easy.

Can someone please point me in the right direction of how to even solve this? It feels so overwhelming

Comment: It's that easy. Think now in the derivative.

Comment: I think you mean $f(4)=3$, and yes, it is that easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're given that a line is tangent to a function at $(4, 3)$. Thus, this point has to lie on the curve, and so $f(4) = 3$.

Now, consider that you have two points on the tangent line, $(4, 3)$ and $(0, 2)$. You can find the slope of the line passing through these points, and that will give you $f'(4)$.